# Sorting database tables according to their FK's connections to determine creation order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very interesting scenario and I really am looking for any idea on how to proceed.
I have schema with around 60 tables. I want find a way to order the tables based on their FKs connections to determine their creation order. What I mean is

I'm providing very simple example of what I try to achieve.

We have table `USERS` with columns `id`,`role_id`, table`ROLES` with columns `id` and `name` and table `TASKS` with columns `id`, `user_id` and `name`.

`USERS.user_id` is a FK to `ROLES.id` and `TASKS.user_id` is a FK to `USERS.id`

So when creating the schema the creation order of tables should be 1st `ROLES`, 2nd `USERS` and 3rd `TASKS`, to be able to add FK constraints by the time of creation without table altering.

Is there a tool or maybe some idea of SQL query which can give me that picture, because for 3 tables it's relatively easy, but for 60 tables with a lot of FK connections this will be a nightmare. Thanks in advance. The database I am using is SQL server.

Comment: I am not sure if it is suitable for your situation, but would like to suggest the following: Script1 - tables creation (without any constraints), Script2 - primary keys creation for tables from Script1, Script3-  foreign keys creation

Comment: I've added an answer. I'm not sure if it will work exactly as you want. But may serve the core purpose.

Comment: @Sergey this is the approach in general, but here for some specific needs it's not applicable.

Comment: Regarding a tool, [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) will handle the correct dependency order. SSDT projects support is included with all VS editions, including the free community one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works.

```
DECLARE @IndependentTables TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(256)
)

DECLARE @Tables TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(256)
)

INSERT INTO @IndependentTables
SELECT object_id, NAME
FROM sys.tables
WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT parent_object_id FROM sys.foreign_keys)

INSERT INTO @Tables
SELECT * FROM @IndependentTables

DECLARE @id INT,
        @name VARCHAR(256)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.object_id, tbl.name
FROM sys.foreign_keys keys
JOIN sys.tables tbl ON tbl.object_id = keys.referenced_object_id

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    -- Relations
    INSERT INTO @Tables
    SELECT tbl.object_id, tbl.name
    FROM sys.tables tbl
    JOIN (SELECT referenced_object_id
        FROM sys.foreign_keys
        WHERE parent_object_id = @id) keys ON keys.referenced_object_id = tbl.object_id
    WHERE tbl.object_id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @Tables)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @id, @name
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

INSERT INTO @Tables
SELECT object_id, NAME
FROM sys.tables
WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @Tables)

SELECT Name FROM @Tables
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will test and see if this suits my needs and change something if needed to adjust. Also I've found a way to acquire those dependencies through Java, which I will also try. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why bother?

Create all the tables *without foreign key relationships*.

Then add the foreign keys using `alter table`.

Note that the method of defining foreign key relationships as an acyclic graph is a fool's errand.  SQL allows:

- Foreign keys to reference the same table, say `employees` have a boss.
- Foreign keys to have cycles.  Say, `projects` have an `owner` and people have a "main project".